# How can I take high resolution videos with rpicam-vid?

Tags: camera, video, libcamera

I want to take a video from my dual camera, using rpicam-vid. The desired resolution is 3200 x 1300

I have tried using h264 but as commented [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpicam-apps/issues/23) and also [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=303956) The h.264 encoder is limited to 1920x1080

What to do...

I tried

```
rpicam-vid -t 10000 --width 3200 --height 1300 --codec mjpeg
```

which succesfully shows me a stream with the resolution I want

But!

how can I save it to a file?

I tried the option `-o output.mjpeg` and it generated a file and everything, but when I try to play it, it seems it contains only the first static picture...